# C# версия джавовского .in() метода

Tags: java, c#, realm

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть решение моей проблемы для джавы:

```
realm.where(Foo.class).in("id", ids).findAll();
```

оно находит все элементы класса foo в базе данных которые входят в список айдишников `ids`

Мне пришлось написать костыль:

```
public interface IKeyedEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class RealmServiceWrapper<T> where T: RealmObject, IKeyedEntity
{
    public List<T> Get(List<string> ids)
    {
        return _db.Realm.All<T>().Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Но он все равно не работает ибо с реалмом нельзя пользоватся конструкцией `.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))`:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Contains' is not supported'

Итак сам вопрос: есть ли альтернатива `.in()` в шарпе?

Comment: Foo.class в первом коде - это что? Тип обьекта или экземпляр?

Comment: Я не знаю realm. Если realm - это список обьектов, полученных в стиле ef, то realm.Where(obj => ids.Contains(obj.id)) должно работать. А что значит элементов, вложенных в элементы? У вас вложенные классы что ли?

Comment: @Александр на сколько я понимаю тип обьекта. Я сам шарпер)

Comment: @Александр реалм не поддерживает этот синтаксис. Про вложенные обьекты забудь, я немного проапдейтил вопрос.

Comment: судя по инфе на их сайте https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/ вы движетесь в правильном направлении. Там есть пример с классом Dog и выборкой из него через условие d.Age == 1, значит Where работает, а d - это по сути экземпляр вложенного объекта, раз может обращаться к его свойствам. Если id - это свойство или поле стринг этого объекта, а ids -  массив стрингов, то, мне кажется, нет никаких причин, чтобы contains не работало

Comment: контеинс сработает исключительно в случае если перед этим поставить `.ToList()` но это не вариант ибо тогда я буду работать со всей таблицей а не делать выборку из таблицы по некоему параметру. Контейнс же в выборках из БД не поддерживается, как и написано в самом вопросе.

Comment: Ограничение вашей orm, видимо, т.к. ef, например, умеет транслировать такие конструкции в sql и выполнять на серверной стороне. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641671/6766879

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704707/2881286) предлагают просто собрать Expression вида: `a ==ids[0] || a == ids[1]` т .д.

Comment: @АндрейNOP это не ORM. Это именно база данных. Да, она имеет свои ограничения, но, как по мне, для будничных и небольших проэктов профита от нее значительно больше чем от SQL+ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути `Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))` это то же самое, что и `Where(a => a.Id == ids[0] || a.Id == ids[1] || ...)`, поэтому можно написать метод расширения, собирающий такое выражение "вручную":

```
public static class MyQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> In<T, TProp>(this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propSelector, IEnumerable<TProp> values)
    {
        var @params = propSelector.Parameters;
        var propAcc = propSelector.Body;
        Expression body = Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool));
        foreach (var v in values)
            body = Expression.OrElse(body,
                Expression.Equal(propAcc,
                    Expression.Constant(v, typeof(TProp))));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, @params);
        return source.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

Такой способ имеет несколько преимуществ перед заданием условия для фильтрации в виде строки: во-первых, не нужно тратить ресурсы на парсинг строки в дерево выражений, дерево у нас уже есть сразу, во-вторых, компилятор проверит, что такое свойство уже реально существует (не даст опечататься) и добавит типизации, т.е. не будет лишних упаковок/распаковок и бессмысленных сравнений строк с числами или т.п.

---

Пример использования:

```
_db.Realm.All<T>().In((a)=>a.Id, ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using Realms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ReLife.Services.RealmRelated.RealmExtensions
{
    public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> In<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, List<string> objList) where T : RealmObject
        {
            var query = string.Join(" OR ", objList.Select(i => $"{propertyName} == '{i}'"));
            return source.Filter(query);
        }

        public static IQueryable<T> In<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, List<int> objList) where T : RealmObject
        {
            var query = string.Join(" OR ", objList.Select(i => $"{propertyName} == {i}"));
            return source.Filter(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Что дало мне возможность сделать вот так:

```
public IQueryable<T> Get(List<string> ids, string idPropertyName = "Id")
{
    return _db.Realm.All<T>().In(idPropertyName,ids);
}
```

Comment: Лучше уж тогда вместо `string propertyName` передавать `Expression<Func<T, TProp>>` и третьим параметром `IEnumerable<TProp>`, но да, это уже детали

Comment: Спасибо за критику... Но с такими "нанотехнологиями" дела не имел =( Можешь помочь с актуализацией кода под твой совет? А то я думал как написать более универсально, но ничего в голову не пришло

Comment: Вот это попробуйте, лямбда вроде правильная генерируется, в деле проверить не могу: https://pastebin.com/aLANZwLc

Comment: Спасибо, разберу код немногим позже. А вообще я нашел еще более оптимальное решение, сейчас обновлю ответ...

Comment: Мне не нравится вариант с формированием строки запроса – помимо затрат на парсинг строки ещё и теряем проверку на корректность введенных свойств и прочего во время компиляции

Comment: Думаю это сыграет роль только на больших базах данных. Думаю что фильтрации тем фильтром строкой будет достаточно для 99 случаев из 100. Для остального процента -- можно будет использовать код с ручным созданием квери, так что убирать его с ответа на всякий случай не буду.

Comment: Спасибо большое за потраченное время и помощь!

Comment: на всякий случай проверил твой код, выдает ошибку: "System.NotSupportedException: 'The left-hand side of the Or operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm.
Unable to process ''.'"

Comment: но, фиксить, наверное, это уже безсмысленно. Еще раз спасибо за потраченное время!

Comment: Какой-то баг в библиотеке, исправил `Or` на `OrElse` и всё заработало, по идее должно работать и так и так

Comment: Давай, тогда добавишь свой рабочий код как отдельный ответ написав что он работает быстрее и я его отмечу как верный :)

Comment: @Andrew, в sql вроде как есть встроенная инструкция in https://myrusakov.ru/sql-operator-in.html. может, проще ее использовать, чем or? Запрос как минимум будет компактнее

Comment: реалм это не ORM SQLя, это отдельная база данных :) Окроме того 'in' внутри скорее всего является надстройкой над OR...

Comment: Хотел ещё добавить, что если All<>() реализует IEnumerable либо IIterable, то можно в расширении внутри foreach проверить id на equals с каждым элементом списка, не прибегая к ручному созданию запроса

Comment: Там `IQueryble`. И нужно как раз что бы и оставалось `IQueryble` что бы запрос был внутри базы данных, а не итерация по элементам результата запроса. Это как раз правильный подход работы с реалмом(да и любой бд). А если сначала применить, например, `.ToList()` то тогда не нужно будет и итерировать по элементам а использовать все возможности LINQ (приблизительно это предложил ты, только менее удобно). Но тогда это просто вопиющий быдлокодище, который будет зря тратить ресурсы системы и который не может работать с большими таблицами.