# Entity Framework 6. Как реализовать метод расширения для навигационного свойства?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Имеются две сущности `Person` и `Post`.

```
public class Person
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Также имеется метод расширения для `ICollection<Post> Posts`

```
public static IEnumerable<Post> GetShortPosts(this IEnumerable<Post> posts)
{
   return posts.Where(q => q.Name.Length < 2);
}
```

Во время использования появляется ошибка

```
using (var context = new PersonDbContext())
{
   var persons = context.Persons.Select(q => new
   {
     PersonName = q.FullName,
     PersonPosts = q.Posts.GetShortPosts()
   }).ToList();
}
```

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Entity.Post]
GetShortPosts(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Entity.Post])' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

Мне необходима сериализация объекта, поэтому отказаться от `ToList()` нельзя.

Каким образом необходимо реализовать метод расширения, чтобы исправить данную ошибку?

Заранее благодарю.

***PS:*** Желательно найти решение без использования `AsEnumerable()` к `context.Persons`

Comment: а что если `IEnumerable<Post>` заменить на `IQueryable<Post>`?

Comment: @Bald не поможет: сам по себе вызов GetShortPosts не транслируется в SQL

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как тогда в этом случае быть? только так: `q.Posts.Where()`?. т.е. явно там где надо

Comment: @Blad @PavelMayorov при использовании прямого вызова `Where()` все работает, однако хотелось бы реализовать именно через методы расширения, чтобы отказаться от дублирования кода

Comment: Связанные вопросы [тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987) и [тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556994/213987)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, есть какие-нибудь наводки на данную тему?

Comment: @Bald, тут скорее проблема в том, что `ICollection<>` не реализует `IQueryable<>`, поэтому переписать сигнатуру метода недостаточно — им невозможно будет воспользоваться. Нужно переписывать тогда и сам запрос: вместо доступа через навигационное свойство использовать `Join` (либо, может, что-то можно сделать с самой сущностью? заменить в сущности `ICollection<>` на `IQueryable<>` можно? будет работать?). После этих манипуляций я бы задумался — возможно, овчинка выделки не стоит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP замена `ICollection<>` на `IQueryable<>` в сущности невозможна, т.к. используется `DbModelBuilder` при построении БД. Описание связи через `HasMany()` возможно только при использовании `ICollection<>` у навигационного свойства. Это техническое ограничение Lazy-Loading

Answer (score 3):

Исправляем в методе `GetShortPosts` интерфейс `IEnumerable` на `IQueryable`, и пишем:

```
var persons = 
  from person in context.Persons
  join post in context.Posts.GetShortPosts() on person.Id equals post.PersonId into posts
  select new {
    PersonName = person.FullName,
    PersonPosts = posts,
  }
```

Если продолжит ругаться на вызов GetShortPosts - его следует вынести в отдельную переменную:

```
var shortPosts = context.Posts.GetShortPosts();
var persons = //...
```

---

В качестве альтернативы, можете попробовать написать свой ExpressionVisitor, который бы преобразовал вызов GetShortPosts в другое дерево выражений.

```
var persons = context.Persons.Select(...).Expand().ToList()

public static IQueryable<T> Expand<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var expr = new ExpandVisitor().Visit(query.Expression);
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expr);
}

class ExpandVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (...) ...;

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

---

Возможно, вам пригодится пакет DelegateDecompiler. Но предупреждаю, у него есть куча ограничений, которые предстоит выявить экспериментально.

```
var persons = context.Persons.Select(...).Decompile().ToList();

[Computed]
public static IEnumerable<Post> GetShortPosts(this IEnumerable<Post> posts) { ... }
```

Comment: Не понял, зачем сам запрос переписывать и почему исправления на `IQueryable` недостаточно. Вот здесь сработало: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928517/218063

Comment: Можно для верности явно написать, что нам надо именно Expression: `Expression<Func<Post, bool>> e = q => q.Name.Length < 2;` и потом `return posts.Where(e);`

Comment: Ага, понял, `ICollection<>` не реализует же `IQueryable<>`. Верно, придется переписывать доступ через навигационное свойство на обычный `Join`

Comment: Использование через отдельную переменную и смены интерфейса вариант рабочий, но не хочется отходить от использования навигационного свойства. Буду смотреть в сторону `ExpressionVisitor`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP тут дело не в том кто чего реализует, а в том где ваш метод используется. Если метод используется только снаружи запроса - достаточно исправить на `IQueryable<>`. А если метод используется внутри запроса - то нужен способ рассказать EF что именно этот метод делает.

Comment: @АндрейNOP собственно, именно потому я и предлагаю вытащить метод GetShortPosts наружу

Answer (score -1):

Нашел вариант – переехал на `Entity Framework Core`. Там работает из коробки.

Comment: Вы же сказали что вам AsEnumerable не устраивает! А ведь Entity Framework Core фактически именно так и делает.

Comment: Да, но в `Entity Framework` мне необходимо это явно прописывать, а в `EF Core` вся эта кухня спрятана.

Comment: @PavelMayorov , буду признателен, если дадите наводку по данной теме в EF Core

Comment: Проблема же не в прописывании, а в том что из базы тянутся лишние данные, и хорошо ещё если одним запросом...

Comment: Держите наводку: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: 1) Проблема в прописывании - каждому разработчику команды придется знать о том, что необходимо использовать `AsEnumerable`. Если этого не сделать, то будет рантайм ошибка, а не ошибка компиляции.

2) После воспроизведения похожего примера на `EFCore` в бд уходит такой запрос 

`SELECT [q.Posts].[Id], [q.Posts].[BlogId], [q.Posts].[Content], [q.Posts].[Title], [t].[Id]
FROM [Posts] AS [q.Posts]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [q0].[Id]
    FROM [Blogs] AS [q0]
) AS [t] ON [q.Posts].[BlogId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]` Никаких лишних данных, все дергается одним запросом. Разве это плохо?

Comment: Вообще-то плохо. Вам надо загрузить только короткие посты, а вы все загрузили. Учитывая, что у вас в запросе есть что-то про блоги, а блог может писаться годами...

Comment: И да, ошибка в рантайме - это хорошо, она вываливается сразу же и ловится при тестировании. Можно даже автоматически. А вот деградация производительности может сыграть злую шутку...