# Linq to entity реализация not in для sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public List<BarPriceDTO> GetBarPricesNotIn(string shop_id, List<BarPriceDTO> barPrices)
{
    try
    {
        var rd = this.db.BarPriceRepository.Read(r => !barPrices.Any(s => s.bar == r.bar && s.shop_id == r.shop_id)).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}  {e.InnerException}");
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Loyalty.API.DTO.Backoffice.BarPriceDTO'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, `r => ...` передаётся у Вас в качестве Expression в методы EF? Если да, то так не получится. EF не может построить константный SQL-запрос на базе Вашей коллекции `barPrices`. Так что либо соберите Expression вручную для всех элементов коллекции, либо сначала прочитайте все сущности из бд, после чего уже итерируйтесь по ним

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а как ввобще можно реализовать not in с помощью linq? Может есть какие-либо другие способы

Comment: Да тут дело не столько в not in, сколько в том, что Вы заставляете EF работать с непримитивными типами

Comment: @Kir_Antipov возможно как то можно заставить? например реализовать какой-нибудь интерфес в модели....сам искал, но ничего годного не нашел

Comment: Вместо автоматической сборки Expression с помощью Linq просто соберите таковой вручную. Пройдитесь по каждому элементу Вашего barPrices, для всех них создайте Expression, который сводится к работе с примитивами, после чего объедините эти выражения с помощью Expression.Or, после чего возьмите от полученного общего выражения отрицание с помощью Expression.Not. И уже этот сформированный Expression пересдавайте в EF. Так как там нет итераций по непонятным для EF коллекциям и сущностям, а все сведено к обычным NOT, OR, AND, =, то EF его поймёт

Comment: Я бы с радостью показал, но по причинам, описанным в профиле, больше здесь не отвечаю из идеологических соображений ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: И да, добавьте в вопрос модель Вашего BarPriceDto. В особенности - полей bar и shop_id. (Не ленитесь, кстати, ставить свойствам нормальные имена. Если же оно отличается от того, что записано в базе, подкорректируйте через ModelBuilder)

Comment: Пробуйте так: `var bars = barPrices.Select(s => s.bar).ToList(); var shopIds = barPrices.Select(s => s.shop_id).ToList();` и потом `....Read(r => !bars.Contains(r.bar) && !shopIds.Contains(r.shop_id))...`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: кстати, тоже вариант. Должно помочь

Comment: @АндрейNOP это не верное условие, т к shop_id и bar - это уникальный индекс в БД. По вашему условию могут провериться разные объекты, что повлечет ненужное удаление объекта.

Comment: Тогда делайте с генерацией Expression, как я говорил, если вариант АндрейNOP не подходит

Comment: Ага, понял. Ну тогда смотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928517/218063 и модифицируйте код из него

Comment: У Вас получилось?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov пока не пробовал, т к другими задачами загрузили...но обязательно поробую ;)

Comment: Напишите потом) Если не выйдет - придётся мне таки согрешить и написать ответ хД